# Elasticsearch java client concatenating terms

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am building an elasticsearch TermsFilterBuilder using the java client so this it has an array of 3 elements with the values [3, 4, 5]. I can see in the debugger that the "values" property is this array of 3 elements.

However, when the query is sent off to elasticsearch it concatenates all of the values like this:

```
  {
        "terms" : {
          "offer.accommodation.rating" : [ 345 ]
  }
```

This is causing my query to fail. Why is it doing this?

Comment: why is it concatenating terms?

Comment: it is the real data or you missed a {

Comment: yeah I copied and pasted and reformatted incorrectly.

Comment: Please post the code you're using to build the filter.